# jQuery .html() vs .append()

Tags: jquery, html

Lets say I have an empty div:

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Is this:

```
$('#myDiv').html("<div id='mySecondDiv'></div>");
```

The same as:

```
var mySecondDiv=$("<div id='mySecondDiv'></div>");
$('#myDiv').append(mySecondDiv);
```

Comment: no, the second one doesn't have an id, so the same text won't be output.

Comment: .html is much faster after you run it first time. it might take second or so when you run it first time.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Whenever you pass a string of HTML to any of jQuery's methods, this is what happens:

A temporary element is created, let's call it x. x's `innerHTML` is set to the string of HTML that you've passed. Then jQuery will transfer each of the produced nodes (that is, x's `childNodes`) over to a newly created document fragment, which it will then cache for next time. It will then return the fragment's `childNodes` as a fresh DOM collection.

Note that it's actually a lot more complicated than that, as jQuery does a bunch of cross-browser checks and various other optimisations. E.g. if you pass just `<div></div>` to `jQuery()`, jQuery will take a shortcut and simply do `document.createElement('div')`.

**EDIT**: To see the sheer quantity of checks that jQuery performs, have a look [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L302), [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L393) and [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L455).

---

`innerHTML` is *generally* the faster approach, although don't let that govern what you do all the time. jQuery's approach isn't quite as simple as `element.innerHTML = ...` -- as I mentioned, there are a bunch of checks and optimisations occurring.

---

The correct technique depends heavily on the situation. If you want to create a large number of identical elements, then the last thing you want to do is create a massive loop, creating a new jQuery object on every iteration. E.g. the quickest way to create 100 divs with jQuery:

```
jQuery(Array(101).join('<div></div>'));
```

---

There are also issues of readability and maintenance to take into account.

This:

```
$('<div id="' + someID + '" class="foobar">' + content + '</div>');
```

... is *a lot* harder to maintain than this:

```
$('<div/>', {
    id: someID,
    className: 'foobar',
    html: content
});
```

Comment: jQuery(Array(101).join('<div></div>')); <-- why 101 instead of 100 ?

Comment: Just wanted to add a datapoint.  Doing some performance testing on an app that loads a large (10K+) batch of <li>'s into a <ul> and saw an increase in render (not load) time from ~12s -> .25s by switching the .append(giantListHTMLAsASingleString) to .html(giantListHTMLAsASingleString).  If you are alreadying doing the 'join' trick or building up a big html string on your list there is definitely a perf diff in these two method.

Comment: @tacone Because the joining "glue" is applied **between** the array elements. `101` will have 100 glues applied, just like joining 3 elements would have 2 glues: `EL-glue-EL-glue-EL`. In James' example, the array elements are "empty" so joining N empty elements results in N-1 consecutive glues.

Comment: For those interested in a reference for the jquery syntax used above and what is allowed see http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes.

Comment: There is a big difference in that it loses whatever data was attached to the doms.

Comment: It appears you need `'class'` (in quotes) rather than `className`:  The name "class" must be quoted in the object since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it refers to the DOM property, not the attribute. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 80):

They are not the same. The first one *replaces* the HTML without creating another jQuery object first. The second creates an additional jQuery wrapper for the second div, then *appends* it to the first.

*One jQuery Wrapper* (per example):

```
$("#myDiv").html('<div id="mySecondDiv"></div>');

$("#myDiv").append('<div id="mySecondDiv"></div>');
```

*Two jQuery Wrappers* (per example):

```
var mySecondDiv=$('<div id="mySecondDiv"></div>');
$('#myDiv').html(mySecondDiv);

var mySecondDiv=$('<div id="mySecondDiv"></div>');
$('#myDiv').append(mySecondDiv);
```

You have a few different use cases going on. If you want to replace the content, `.html` is a great call since its the equivalent of `innerHTML = "..."`. However, if you just want to append content, the extra `$()` wrapper set is unneeded.

Only use two wrappers if you need to manipulate the added `div` later on. Even in that case, you still might only need to use one:

```
var mySecondDiv = $("<div id='mySecondDiv'></div>").appendTo("#myDiv");
// other code here
mySecondDiv.hide();
```

Comment: You see? The string concatenation already let to an error here (unescaped quote). see my post :P

Answer (score 23):

if by `.add` you mean `.append`, then the result is the same if `#myDiv` is empty.

is the performance the same? dont know.

`.html(x)` ends up doing the same thing as `.empty().append(x)`

Comment: Also, the first one would obviously have an id of mySecondDiv while the other would have no id on it.  And the syntax would need to be .html("<div id='mySecondDiv'></div>") using double quotes in order to be able to use the single quotes.

Answer (score 12):

`.html()` will replace everything.

`.append()` will just append at the end.

Answer (score 11):

Well, `.html()` uses `.innerHTML` which is faster than [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) creation.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the second method to achieve the same effect by:

```
var mySecondDiv = $('<div></div>');
$(mySecondDiv).find('div').attr('id', 'mySecondDiv');
$('#myDiv').append(mySecondDiv);
```

Luca mentioned that `html()` just inserts hte HTML which results in faster performance.

In some occassions though, you would opt for the second option, consider:

```
// Clumsy string concat, error prone
$('#myDiv').html("<div style='width:'" + myWidth + "'px'>Lorem ipsum</div>");

// Isn't this a lot cleaner? (though longer)
var newDiv = $('<div></div>');
$(newDiv).find('div').css('width', myWidth);
$('#myDiv').append(newDiv);
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient (and broken) jQuery code. If you want to avoid concatenation do this: (also note `px` is not needed): `$('<div />', { width: myWidth }).appendTo("#myDiv");`

Comment: How is this "not useful"? The poster asked for the "difference" (keyword is "vs") so I tell him the difference. The code is verbose but I wouldn't say "inefficient" just because the fact that it's not a one liner. Shouldn't we be verbose when explaining stuffs to people?

Answer (score 2):

Other than the given answers, in the case that you have something like this:

```
<div id="test">
    <input type="file" name="file0" onchange="changed()">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isAllowed = true;
    function changed()
    {
        if (isAllowed)
        {
            var tmpHTML = $('#test').html();
            tmpHTML += "<input type=\"file\" name=\"file1\" onchange=\"changed()\">";
            $('#test').html(tmpHTML);
            isAllowed = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

meaning that you want to automatically add one more file upload if any files were uploaded, the mentioned code will not work, because after the file is uploaded, the first file-upload element will be recreated and therefore the uploaded file will be wiped from it. You should use .append() instead:

```
    function changed()
    {
        if (isAllowed)
        {
            var tmpHTML = "<input type=\"file\" name=\"file1\" onchange=\"changed()\">";
            $('#test').append(tmpHTML);
            isAllowed = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me . Jquery version : 3.3. 
If you are looping through a list of objects, and want to add each object as a child of some parent dom element, then .html and .append will behave very different. `.html` will end up adding only the last object to the parent element, whereas `.append` will add all the list objects as children of the parent element.