# function poll with button create

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery script. This should, as I've thought it, take the number of `templateTotal` (the total number of Templates which exist on USB) from the *JSON* and generate as many buttons, as `templateTotal` indicates.

For example if `templateTotal` is *6*, then the script should generate 6 buttons.

```
(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/status",
            processData: true,
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                var template = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var templateButton = "";
                for (i = 1; i > templateTotal; i++);
                templateButton +=  '<button class="templateButton" id="T' + i + '" formaction="/api/template" post="template=' + i + '">T' + i + '</button>'
            },
            complete: poll
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: please tel wat is isse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semi colon after the `for` loop:

```
 for(i=1; i > templateTotal; i++);
```

It should be:

```
 for(i=1; i > templateTotal; i++)
                templateButton += '<button class="templateButton" id="T' 
               + i     +'"
               formaction="/api/template"post="template='+i+'">T'+i+'</button>'
```

or

```
for(i=1; i > templateTotal; i++){
    templateButton += 
    '<button class="templateButton" id="T' +   i +
    '" formaction="/api/template"   
     post="template='+i+'">T'+i+'</button>'
}
```

The semicolon indicates the end of a statement (as does the carriage return).  The for loop (unless followed by brackets) will execute the next single statement which the semicolon ends.

A semicolon isn't necessary to end a statement, but it's good practice to put it in.  Omitting it will still create valid syntax.

Comment: @user234110 you are just creating a string, you forgot to append it `.append(templateButton)` or `.html(templateButton)`

Comment: and it will comes where? sry... am a newbew )

Comment: This will get you started in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append

Now that you have created the HTML you have to append it to the DOM in the page.

Answer (score 0):

ur code has 2 errors ,

1)Semicolon after `for`

means for loop will be execured templateTotal times And do nothing.Then

```
  templateButton += '<button class="templateButton" id="T' + i +'" formaction="/api/template" post="template='+i+'">T'+i+'</button>'
```

This code runs once only.So remove semicolon.

2)Also the code

```
  templateButton += '<button class="templateButton" id="T' + i +'" formaction="/api/template" post="template='+i+'">T'+i+'</button>'
```

is missing `;` semicolon.