# Onclick for dynamically created elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onclick event is just not working for me. When mouse in over some div, I dynamically insert some icons using .html() function, and want to set onclick on that icons but i can't. I also tried setting click listener for the static enclosing div (jquery .on('click', ..) function) or for the whole page but it's no use, as if those icons just swallow the click event... Any ideas?

```
<div id="rating" class="pull-right rating-box clearfix">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
</div>
```

Here is html

I have tried a lot of way of doing, but here is the latest thing i tried

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //some code
    $('#rating').html(/* some combination of <i class="fa fa-star"></i>'s */);
    $('#rating').on('click', 'i', function() { });
});
```

Comment: post your code as well

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements) and many, many other questions posted here already. Do a bit of search, please.

Comment: Thank you all for marking my question as duplicate, but I have gone through all the similar questions and none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.append()` method instead:

```
$('#rating').empty();
$('#rating').append(/* some combination of <i class="fa fa-star"></i>'s */);
$('#rating').on('click', 'i', function() { });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLtjm79m/2/)

See [jquery .html() vs .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3015469/909180) for more information.

Comment: But i need to clear the html of the div before calling append. What is the correct way of doing that?

Comment: My fiddle works. There is a star icon at the right, and when clicked an alert is displayed.