# Moving html content around the DOM with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to load the contents of the gallery element to the stage element by clicking on the gallery element itself. This is noob stuff I'm sure, but I have yet to find an explanation for this. Why doesn't this work?

Also, I am using jquery UI to create a drag and drop interface --> the element inside the #gallery is draggable, and #gallery is droppable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $galcon = $('#gallery').html();
    $("#gallery").on('click'function () {
        $('#stage').append($galcon);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing a comma between `'click'` and `function`

Comment: when you want to use HTML tags, use `html()` method. When you are referring to jQuery nodes, use `.append()`. i.e either drop `.html()` from "`$('#gallery').html()`" or change `.append()` to `.html()` in "`$('#stage').append($galcon)`". Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append) for a detailed discussion on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the actual node child and not just the html. In other words, remove the ".html()"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $galcon = $('#gallery');
    $("#gallery").on('click'function () {
        $('#stage').append($galcon);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `var $galcon = $('#gallery').html()` with `var $galcon = $('#gallery').text()`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error in the dev console? Is this the exact code you're running? You need a comma after 'click':

```
$("#gallery").on('click', function () {
    $('#stage').append($galcon);
});
```