# Jquery append and html

Tags: javascript, jquery

**updated**
At the beginning, when I click button, item from function `checkinforfun` loop again and again. And I wish to delete the previous to prevent it only show once.

OK now, so far i have found one way to not "delete" , is to change `append` to `html` , but when I change to `html` all item in function `checkinforfun` doesn't show completely

```
    if (i === checkin_info.length - 1) {
        $(".checkin_progress").append(check_progress_day);
    } else {
        $(".checkin_progress").append(check_progress_day + check_progress_dot1 + check_progress_dot2 + check_progress_dot3);

    }
```

[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/pd9prvL1/)

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/7g37eos5/1/)

Comment: When using `html` it doesn't show completely because everytime the new data replaces the old one..

Comment: @Outlooker but if i use back to `append` every time i clicked , item will keep adding again and again

Comment: When u are using html it replaces the entire content.Try putting an alert inside the if statement to really know how its working..

Comment: @Outlooker i know how it work , if u have a solution for prevent the function only show once then will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be emptying the div that has a class named `checkin_progress`.So each time you click on the button it will clear the previous html content and your function adds the new content.

```
$(".checkin_progress").empty();
    $.each(checkin_info, function (i, obj) {
            //Other code;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8o9L1ye7/)

**FYI**

[empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

[append vs html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append)