# Auto complete search is not working properly, do not iterate all elements in $.each ul li shows on time in response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have implemented auto complete search in my site. The problem is that response is coming properly but it do not iterate all elements in `<ul><li>` elements. 
Always shows one element in HTML but coming multiple from response.

On the top search see if you type only river it comes with river records but do not show all in one `ul li` means `li` iteration is not working.

Here is my Jquery code:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#keyword').keyup(function() {
        var total;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://realtyexecutivesny.com/getRecSet.php?rnd=" + Math.random(),
            data:{ key: $(this).val() },
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data.locations, function( key, value ) {
                    total =  '<li>'+data.locations[0].value+'</li>';
                });
               $('#lists').html('<ul>'+total+'</ul>'); 
            }
        });
    });
    $('#lists ul li').click(function(){
        $('#keyword').val($(this).html());
        $('#field').val($(this).parent().data('field'));
    });
    });
</script>
```

Here is HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
<input type="hidden" name="field" id="field" value="all" />
<div id="lists"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.append()` it's a more clean approach.

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#lists').html('<ul></ul>') // initiate clear element
    $.each(data.locations, function (key, value) {
        $('#lists ul').append('<li>' + data.locations[key].value + '</li>'); // append new elements to the ul element
    });
}
```

Also check this: [jquery .html() vs .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append)

Comment: your solution seems working for me but it is iterating not properly means records are not showing what I have in response. Please test using `river` in my site and see response and data.

Comment: Now it should work !  just put `value` not the `data.locations`:) ,and `key` gives you the iterator

Comment: If I click on li element it is not putting it in textfield. Please see.

Comment: I am in chat. It saying you have only 19 reputations so cant do chat. If you can please upvote my question.

Comment: I did, how about now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73141/discussion-between-urahara-and-testing).

Answer (score 2):

first Initialize total like

```
var total = '';
```

And in your `each`, Use `index` to get all records.

```
$.each(data.locations, function( index ) {
     total +=  '<li>' + data.locations[index].value + '</li>';
});

$('#lists').html('<ul>' + total + '</ul>');
```

Comment: `locations: [{value: "Wading River, NY", altValue: null, display: "Wading River, NY", type: "city",…},…]
0: {value: "Wading River, NY", altValue: null, display: "Wading River, NY", type: "city",…}
1: {value: "Riverhead, NY", altValue: null, display: "Riverhead, NY", type: "city", propertyIndex: "",…}
2: {value: "Wading River, NY", altValue: null, display: "Wading River, NY", type: "city",…}
3: {value: "Wading River, NY", altValue: null, display: "Wading River, NY", type: "city",…}
4: {value: "Riverhead, NY", altValue: null, display: "Riverhead, NY", type: "city", propertyIndex: "",…}`

Comment: and my listing shows only one element `<ul><li>` that is `Wading River, NY` when it should show all.

Comment: let me try and get back to you.

Comment: No, now it is not showing anything in response. See on website.

Comment: @Testing : because you commented out  this line `$('#lists').html('<ul>'+total+'</ul>'); `

Answer (score -1):

replace this:

```
total =  '<li>'+data.locations[0].value+'</li>';
```

with this:

```
total +=  '<li>'+data.locations[0].value+'</li>';
```

and befor the each loop define total like below:

```
var total = '';
$.each(data.locations, function( key, value ) {
    total +=  '<li>'+data.locations[0].value+'</li>';
});
```

Comment: `data.locations[0]` will return the same value over and over again.

Comment: @Urahara yes it will, I did not see the index, use index of the each loop, Thanks. :)