# Difference between append and html in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What does the difference of `html()` and `append()` when it comes to jQuery
because if I use `append()` it will display my data in the next line while if I use `html()` it will just overwrite the first data being displayed...

Now what I want is the function of `html()` but displaying it in the next line instead of overwriting the previous data displayed and if the previous data is already being displayed it will just highlight it instead of appending it in the next line  here is my javascript code

```
html2 += '<div class="rightcontainer">';
html2 += '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png" onclick="DisplayProfileCard();"/>';
html2 += '<div id="imagedetail">';
html2 += '<span class="details">Product Type:' + flsSites[index].serial_number +'</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Version / Size <img class="row_one_icon lightbulb_icon" id="lightbulb" src="src/images/lightbulb1.png" onClick="LightBulb()" /><img id="convert" class="row_one_icon arrow_icon" src="src/images/arrow_Off.png" onClick="Conversion()"/><img id="lightning" class="row_one_icon" src="src/images/lightningOff.png" onClick="Lightning()"/><img id="bullseye" class="row_one_icon bullseye" src="src/images/bullseye_off.png" onClick="BullsEye()"/></span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend <img class="row_one_icon ribbon" src="src/images/ribbon1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon map" src="src/images/map1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon paper_stack" id="paper" src="src/images/paper_stack_Off.png" onclick="PaperStack()"/><img class="row_one_icon chain" id="chain" src="src/images/chain_Off.png" onClick="ChainLink()"/></span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>';
html2 += '</div>'
html2 += '</div>';
$('#resultcontainer').append(html2);
$('.rightcontainer').eq($(this).index()).addClass('background');
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: use `.after()` http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: $('#').html() will completely replace the content inside the tag that the selector corresponds to. $('#').append() will just append to the end of the content inside the tag.

Comment: This is known question in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append

Comment: add and show your code.
But yes you can do it with .innerHTML . you just need to concat the value and not just insert it

Comment: @SidBhalke hi I have added my codes just to support my explanation

Answer (score 2):

`$(el).html()` replace everything that is inside the selector.

```
 <div class="el">
      <!-- Everything here gets replaced -->
 </div>
```

`$(el).append()` puts inside selector at the end.

```
 <div class="el">
      [...]
      <!-- appends it here -->
 </div>
```

`$(el).prepend()` puts inside selector at the begining.

```
 <div class="el">
      <!-- preprend it here -->
      [...]
 </div>
```

`$(el).before()` puts outside before the selector.

```
 <!-- appends it here -->
 <div class="el">
      [...]
 </div>
```

`$(el).after()` puts outside after selector.

```
 <div class="el">
      [...]
 </div>
 <!-- appends it here -->
```

Comment: `append()` is adding innerHTML/children element at the last, not after an element. that would be the work of `after()` function.

Comment: Yes i corrected oninross's answer, please don't down vote now