# .append() vs .html() in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm, struggling a little bit trying to understand the way .append and .html works.
I have this code which generates a new `<li>` element when clicking a button:

The way that it's written below works fine. The thing is that if instead of .html() I use .append() it add a new `<li>` plus all the others, not just ONE `<li>`

Can someone explain to me why does it happen?
Thanks in advance :)

```js
const showTask = () =>{
    let itemHtml = "";
    toDoList.forEach((item, index)=>{
        
        itemHtml += 
            `<li class="item ${item.isCompleted == true ? " item-is-done" : ""}" id="${index}"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><span>${item.task}</span>               
                <button type="button" class="remove" onClick="deleteTask(${index})"><i class="bi bi-trash" id="remove-btn"></i></button>
            </li>`;
    });

    $(".list").html(itemHtml);
};
```

Comment: `.html()` replaces all the existing content in `.list`. `.append()` does not

Comment: Already exists answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/3015335/6099811

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` overwrites everything of your `.list`.

`.append()` adds the element at the end of your `.list`.

Answer (score 0):

html function remove previous data and write new one you should use append to keep previews

and add new one