# In Jquery when you use .html doesn´t show whatever you have on the id div?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery  when using `.html` as in:

```js
$(‘#notify’).html(‘Want to get notified of single woman living near you?’).slideDown();
```

The jQuery just shows what appears there in the jQuery inside .HTML() and nothing else, but if you instead put:

```js
(“#notify”).slideDown();
```

It shows everything inside the div id #notify

I expected to show both, but just show what appears inside the jQuery code `.html`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .html() vs .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append)

Comment: `.html(..)` replaces everything that is in the element if you weren't aware. [See jQuery.html() docs](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

slideDown() is applied to hidden HTML element to generate slide down effect.If HTML element is visible then no slideDown() effect applied on it.

Comment: yes, this is a good point, but my point is that it wouldn´t show the div if you have .html(..) in the jquery no matter if you slideDown or slideUp, it will display just the .hml(...) content.